# Is there a better way to avoid 'Sign comparison' warning when comparing NSIndexPath's row and NSArray count?

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, nsinteger, nsuinteger

I turned 'Signed Comparision' (aka -Wsign-compare) warnings for my iOS project in XCode (surprisingly, it was off by default). After that lots of warnings like this appeared:

```
/Users/michalciuba/projects/GlobeMobile/Classes/ACMailController.m:86:19: Comparison of integers of different signs: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') and 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')
```

They are usually caused by comparing `row` property of `NSIndexPath` which is `NSInteger` to the value returned by 'count' method of `NSArray`, like this:

```
if(indexPath.row < [self.myDataArray count])
```

The warning can be simply fixed by casting:

```
if(indexPath.row < (NSInteger)[self.myDataArray count])
```

However, it has to be done if every single place where such values are being compared. And they are being compared in dozens of places.
 I wonder if there is a better and more clever way to solve this problem? I don't want to turn off this warning, because it may help to prevent issues like unsigned integer underflow.

Comment: Try with `if(indexPath.row <= self.myDataArray.count-1)`

Comment: This will still trigger a warning. And it will fail when myDataArray is empty (because of NSUInteger underflow). Actually this is why I turned this warning on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a category that does it for you :

```
@implementation NSArray (SignedCount)

- (NSInteger) signedCount
{
    NSInteger count = (NSInteger)[self count];
    return count;
}

@end
```