# Recipes on how to supress / fix "Implicit conversion changes signedness" warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings

I'm modernizing a legacy project and I enabled `-Wconversion` flag on Xcode. Now I have a lot of warning like

> Implicit conversion changes signedness: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned
>   long') to 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')

using code like the following while interacting with a `UITableView`

```
Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`row` is defined as `NSInteger` while `objectAtIndex:` accepts an `NSUInteger`.

Is there a smart way to fix those warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either change the type of the `row` property to return `NSUInteger` or do this:

```
Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)(indexPath.row)];
```

If you do the latter, you might need to check to make sure `row` is positive.

---

**Edit**

Since the `row` is a property of `NSIndexPath` there is clearly a good reason why it might be negative or Apple would have made it an `NSUInteger`, perhaps if there is no item selected, it is set to -1.  So what you should do is make sure that the value of row is not negative and then do the cast above to suppress the warnings, like this:

```
NSInteger row = indexPath.row
if (row >= 0)
{
    Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)row];
}
else
{
    // whatever you need to do for no row available
}
```

Comment: Yep! The cast is the correct way but I think I will get crazy. What do you mean *change the type of the `row` property to return `NSUInteger`*? `row` belongs to `NSIndexPath` class in this case.

Comment: So, *-Wconversion* is enabled or not in your projects?

Comment: @flexaddicted Amended the answer a bit

Comment: Thanks. Are you using *-Wconversion* in your project? Just to know. Yep. The cast is the simplier solution but I think I will go with clang push/pop calls in orders to skip those warnings.

Comment: @flexaddicted Yes, I always turn that one on.  They do indicate a real potential problem with your code.  If the `row` property is negative, you will get an array bounds exception.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you shouldn't try to be "smart".

```
NSUInteger row = (NSUInteger)indexPath.row;
Item* item = self.items [row];
```

Comment: Yep! The cast is the correct way but I think I will get crazy.

Comment: So, *-Wconversion* is enabled or not in your projects?

Comment: The warning is here for a reason. If you do a comparison like `indexPath.row < self.items.count-1`, and `items.count` is 0, the unsigned integer integer on the right side will silently underflow (and become `NSUIntegerMax`), so the result of the comparison will be other than you expected. I wasted few hours of my life because of this subtle bug, after that I always turn this warning on. You can take a look on my question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21724824/2128900

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this warning after I upgraded to Xcode 11.
Going back to Xcode 10 fixed this.